# Remove a text string using notepad ++

Tags: notepad

au/centre/morton?***fbclid=IwAR1jANqDaRYOf5nK2O4Gf5FlD3m9V8ltAnEExTtSpOGqfOomwnEj74S1o-I_aem_AdvyP_31s0CjBjtcRzzsrE5VrKEWE4Ulb_G6RQZp4sFYTvvltfJoTq4CzORC7CEDIoiwQM8WiN3RFcV2-nEVV3CB0ZgbvJ8_XFs6fgBjRnyLZHKu5ltO2cbIU4NBHzDB_Y0***

Any idea how I can remove all the text in bold? I have 20,000 rows that have FBCLID appended to it.
Wondering if someone can teach how to do this on notepad ++ or anything that is simple to execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    \?fbclid=\S+$
Replace: (empty)
```

Here is a working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iDjB4q/1).

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim, the link is amazing, I was fiddling almost close to 2 hours and your demo + explanation really helps me a lot.!